# Should I work with index mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables (Mysql) with 1.000.000 records/table. I know that the Index solution is good to query. But users use about 100-200 Insert or Update queries to change these tables every day. So should i work with index?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It's better to have indexes, although they speed up `select` more than they slow down `insert` queries.

Comment: 100 queries a day is nothing. Why are you worried about performance?

Comment: `UPDATE ... WHERE x = 2` needs `INDEX(x)`, else it will need to scan the entire table.  If you want more discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the actual queries.